# What is probability of choose already choosen when we choose n values from set limited to m (n <= m)?

Tags: probability

I study math many years ago (I am engineer) and not remember how exactly calculate probability for such problem. I choose n values from m set and want calculate probability that all will be unique, has $1$ repeat or less, $2$ repeats or less or $k$ repeats or less.

I have set value $0 .. m$ and I do some choices from this set $n \geq 1$.
Number of choices is less or equal to set size $n \leq m$.
After every choice I return selected value from $0 .. m$ to set.

Maybe it is simple problem but I forget some theory or it is hidden deep in memory and I can not solve it easily.

Examples:

1. if set is $m = 2$ and choice $n = 2$ probability to not choose same value is $\frac{1}{2}.$
2. if set is $m = 3$ and choice $n = 2$ probability to not choose same value is  $\frac{6}{9}$ because $3*3$ permutations and $3$ combos in $2$ orders.
3. if set is $m = 3$ and choices $n = 3$ $->$ $p = \frac{6}{27}$ ($3*3*3$ permutations and $3*2$ combos)

How to generalize it with probability equation?

Comment: What do you mean by $k$ repeats? Granted $1,1$ counts as one repeat, does $1,1,1$ count as two or three repeats?

Comment: 1, 1, 1 is 3 repeats, 1, 1, (not 1) is 2 repeats.

Comment: So $1$ repeat or less is exactly the same as no repeats?

Comment: 1 repeat is (1,1) but 0 repeats can be (0, 1), or (0). 2 repeats can be (1, 1, 1).

Comment: But you just said $1,1,1$ is $3$ repeats.

Answer (score 3):

To calculate the probability of no repeats, observe

*Total ordered sequences* = $m\times m\times \dots\times m = m^n $

*Number of sequences with each element distinct* = $\binom{m}{n} \times n!=\frac{m!}{(m-n)!} $

The probability is thus $$ \frac{m!}{m^n(m-n)!} $$

Comment: Interesting I need check if $$ \prod_{i=0}^{n}\frac{m - i - 1}{m} $$ is $$ \frac{m!}{m^n(m-n)!} $$. It is possible I need think a little.

Comment: Those two aren’t equal. I guess the product you want is $$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{m-i}{m} $$

Comment: @4386427 I did write $n-1$. Write \prod_{lower limit}^{upper limit} .

Comment: @Tavish Thanks for helping with limits.

Answer (score 2):

if n equals 1 you can draw any of the m numbers in the set. So you have

$$\frac{m}{m}$$

if n equals 2 the first draw is as above and in the second draw you can draw one of m-1 numbers in the set. So you have

$$\frac{m}{m}\times\frac{m-1}{m}$$

if n equals 3 the first two draws is as above and in the third draw you can draw one of m-2 numbers in the set. So you have

$$\frac{m}{m}\times\frac{m-1}{m}\times\frac{m-2}{m}$$

and so on.

In general

$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}{\frac{m-i}{m}}$$

or

$$\frac{1}{m^n}\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}{{m-i}}$$

The product will give

$$m\times(m-1)\times(m-2)\times\dots\times(m-n+1)$$

or

$$(m\times(m-1)\times(m-2)\times\dots\times(m-n+1))\times\frac{(m-n)!}{(m-n)!}$$

or

$$\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$$

Putting it all together we get the probabilty of **not** drawing two indentical numbers to be:

$$\frac{m!}{m^n(m-n)!}$$